# How to prevent Jquery script loading twice in ajax call or submit JQuery Function to Ajax Called Page

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, onclick

Hi guys i got a problem with my Code. I load new Page Content on click of Button and got a JQuery Function with onclick which changes a love or like count on Page. If i dont include the JQuery Function into the Ajax loaded page it doesn`t work but if i do he acts twice the function any idea how to fix this or solutions?

This is the JQuery Script from page:

```
$(".toggle").on("click", function(e) {


            $('.alert-box').hide();
        $( '.alert-box' ).remove();
  var $this = $(this);
  var $lovecount = $this.closest("div").find(".lovecount");
  if ($(e.target).hasClass('love')) {
    //alert('Liebe genommen');
  var val = +$lovecount.text() + (this.checked ? -1 : -1);
  $(e.target).prop( "checked", false );

  } else {
    //alert('Liebe gegeben');
  var val = +$lovecount.text() + (this.checked ? 1 : 1);
  $(e.target).prop( "checked", true );

  };
  //var val = +$lovecount.text() + (this.checked ? 1 : -1);
  $lovecount.text(val)
  $('.alert-box').toggle(!this.checked);
  $(this).toggleClass("love");


  var postid = $this.attr("data-post");
  var userid = $this.attr("data-userid");
  dataString = 'userid=' + userid + '&postid=' + postid;

  // Are you not supposed to send the new value to the server?

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'inc/give-love.php',
    data: dataString,
    success: function(response) {
      $('<div class="alert-box success">'+response+'</div>').prependTo('body').delay(3000).fadeOut(1000, function() {

        $('.alert-box').hide();
        $( '.alert-box' ).remove();

      });
    }
  })
})
```

with this i change and toggle input from this HTML Code Structure.

```
<!-- POST ITEM START -->
          <div class="post-item">
            <div class="post-asset image">
              <img src="uploads/<?php echo $row['picture']; ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="post-header">
              <h3 class="post-title"><a href="#" data-loader="show"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></a></h3>
              <span class="post-category">

                <a class="favorite-button" href="#" data-post="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" data-userid="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id'];?>"><span class="favorite-button-icon fa fa-star-o"></span></a>

              </span>

              <span class="post-date font17"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> <?php $timeago=get_timeago(strtotime($row['created'])); echo $timeago;?></span>
              <span class="post-comments font17"><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i> 1,3k Reaktionen</span>
            </div>
            <div class="post-footer">
              <a href="#" class="post-author">
                <span class="author-img"><img src="img/avatar.png"></span>
                <span class="author-name">OnePost von<b><?php echo $row['poster']; ?></b></span>
              </a>
              <div class="post-extra">
                <!--<div class="add-favorite" id="heart-container"><span class="lovecount">112</span><input data-post="123" data-user="Jessica Jones" type="checkbox" id="toggle" onclick="myFunction(this)" checked><div id="twitter-heart" class=""></div></input></div>-->
                <div class="add-favorite" id="heart-container"><a href="#" title="Alle Loves anzeigen"><span class="lovecount"><?php echo $row['loves']; ?></span></a>

                <!--<input data-post="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" data-userid="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id'];?>" type="checkbox" id="toggle" class="toggle love" onclick="myFunction(this)">-->

                <?php
                                if($row['is_liked'] != 1){ ?>

                                <input data-post="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" data-userid="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id'];?>" type="checkbox" id="toggle" class="toggle">

                                <?}else{?>

                                <input data-post="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" data-userid="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id'];?>" type="checkbox" id="toggle" class="toggle love" checked="true">


                <?php }?>


                  <div id="twitter-heart" class=""></div></input></div>
                <div class="post-share"><i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i>
                  <div class="social-links">
                    <a href="#" class="share-facebook social-links-a" data-network="Facebook" data-post="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" data-url="https://onepost.eu/neu/post.php"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                    <a href="#" class="share-twitter social-links-a" data-network="Twitter" data-post="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" data-url="https://onepost.eu/neu/post.php"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                    <a href="#" class="share-google-plus social-links-a" data-network="Pinterest" data-post="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" data-url="https://onepost.eu/neu/post.php"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a>
                    <a href="#" class="share-whatsapp social-links-a" data-network="WhatsApp" data-post="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" data-url="https://onepost.eu/neu/post.php"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i></a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- POST ITEM END -->
```

When i include the JQuery script in Ajax page it fires twice the function if not onclick is not working. How to prevent this or make it working the right way?

Comment: If you're dynamically loading the element(s) that have a `class="toggle"`, then you will want to do something like `$(document).on('click', '.toggle', function (event) { ... });`. Place this code outside of the dynamically loaded content and declare it only once.

Answer (score 0):

If you append any element after DOM has loaded, you need to use `delegate();` selector.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#div1").append('<button id="btn">Click</button>');
//You can use delegate() selector and when you click #btn its works.

$("body").delegate("#btn", "click", function(){
alert("Button has working!");
});
});
```